# Bind tag name in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to bind tag name to variable in AngularJs. Direct way doesn't work:

```
<div ng-app ng-init="list=['pre', 'div', 'em']">
Check the list: {{list}}
<div data-ng-repeat="item in list">
 {{item}}: <{{item}}>content</{{item}}>
</div>
</div>
```

How to do it right?
​

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to want to make a [Directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) and use the [$compile](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile) service module.

Comment: could you be more specific? (code example maybe...)

Answer (score 0):

Angular template system works on DOM tree, not on strings, so template must be valid HTML and usage of {{}} for tagname is impossible. We can write own directive for it (see Max answer) or if here is small set of options it can be more easy to use ng-include and set of templates for  options.